# SQL - lag/delay by YearMonth integer

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this table:

```
| YearMonth | Client_ID |
| 202001    | A         |
| 201903    | A         |
| 201802    | A         |
| 202001    | B         |
| 202001    | B         |
```

And I'm looking for this output, where `YearMonth_1` is `(YearMonth - 1)`, `YearMonth_2` is `(YearMonth - 2)`, and so on:

```
| YearMonth | Client_ID | YearMonth_1 | YearMonth_2 | YearMonth_3 |
| 202001    | A         | 201912      | 201911      | 201910      |
| 201903    | A         | 201902      | 201901      | 201812      |
| 201802    | A         | 201801      | 201712      | 201711      |
| 202001    | B         | 201912      | 201911      | 201910      |
| 201912    | B         | 201911      | 201910      | 201909      |
```

In my real dataset, I have until `YearMonth_8` and my solution is:

```
SELECT YearMonth, Client_ID, (YearMonth - 1) AS YearMonth_1, 
(YearMonth - 2) AS YearMonth_2, (YearMonth - e) AS YearMonth_3
FROM TABLE1
```

And when `YearMonth = 202001`, `YearMonth_1` will be `202000`. I solve this with:

```
UPDATE TABLE1
SET YearMonth_1 = 201912
WHERE YearMonth_1 = 202000
```

It's an easy and fast solution. But when you reach `YearMonth_3` or `YearMonth_8` in my real dataset, I have to `UPDATE` 3 values for `YearMonth_3` or 8 values for `YearMonth_8` when `YearMonth = 20XX01` which is very time-consuming. Is there a more efficient way?

Comment: You have a duplicate yyyymm value on the two "B" rows.  Is that a typo?

Answer (score 1):

I would convert the values to dates:

```
select t.*,
       year(dateadd(month, -1, yyyymm)) * 100 + month(dateadd(month, -1, yyyymm)),
       year(dateadd(month, -2, yyyymm)) * 100 + month(dateadd(month, -2, yyyymm)),
       year(dateadd(month, -3, yyyymm)) * 100 + month(dateadd(month, -3, yyyymm))
from t cross apply
     (values (convert(date, concat(yearmonth, '01')))) v(yyyymm)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should really just store the `EOMONTH(date)` as a `date` instead of a weird `int`.

But you don't need to store the previous 8 values, you can query it on the fly:

```sql
SELECT
    ClientID,
    YearMonth,
    YearMonth_1 = LAG(YearMonth, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY ClientID ORDER BY YearMonth,
    YearMonth_2 = LAG(YearMonth, 2) OVER (PARTITION BY ClientID ORDER BY YearMonth,
    YearMonth_3 = LAG(YearMonth, 3) OVER (PARTITION BY ClientID ORDER BY YearMonth,
    YearMonth_4 = LAG(YearMonth, 4) OVER (PARTITION BY ClientID ORDER BY YearMonth,
    YearMonth_5 = LAG(YearMonth, 5) OVER (PARTITION BY ClientID ORDER BY YearMonth,
    YearMonth_6 = LAG(YearMonth, 6) OVER (PARTITION BY ClientID ORDER BY YearMonth,
    YearMonth_7 = LAG(YearMonth, 7) OVER (PARTITION BY ClientID ORDER BY YearMonth,
    YearMonth_8 = LAG(YearMonth, 8) OVER (PARTITION BY ClientID ORDER BY YearMonth,
FROM t
```

Best to have an index on `(ClientID, YearMonth)`

Comment: But here ´YearMonth_1 = LAG(YearMonth, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY ClientID ORDER BY YearMonth,´ you are assumming it's a date? If you are, what kind of conversion specifically should I do?

Comment: You can do `EOMONTH(DATEFROMPARTS(YearMonth / 100, YearMonth % 100, 1))`